# How to enable/disable gridlines in mp_chart for flutter once chart is drawn

Tags: flutter, mpandroidchart

I am making a chart in flutter using mp_chart package (v 0.1.9).
Chart type is performance line chart.

In the controller definition, I have enabled grid as

```
xAxisSettingFunction: (xAxis, controller) {
    xAxis.enabled = true;

    xAxis
      ..drawGridLines = (true)
      ..setLabelCount1(120)
      ..drawLabels = (false)
      ..drawAxisLine = (false)
      ..granularityEnabled = (true)
      ..setGranularity(5.0);
  },
```

Accordingly I am getting the grid drawn.
Now I want to toggle the grid (hide and unhide)
So I suppose something like this should work

```
myController.xAxis.drawGridLines = false;
setState(() {});
```

Resetting the grid line enable parameter and calling set state.
But its not working.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
After changing the property like

```
myController.xAxis.drawGridLines = false;
```

when the setState() is called. It overrides the value defined in the controller definition.
so to achieve the desired result, we can use a flag (bool) in controller definition.

```
xAxisSettingFunction: (xAxis, controller) {
    xAxis.enabled = true;

    if (flag) {
            xAxis.drawGridLines = true;
          } else {
            xAxis.drawGridLines = true;
          }
  },
```

then change flag as required and call setState()